# Handling prompts from an installer in Linux command line

Tags: linux, bash, script

I am writing a bash script that, amongst other things, installs some software.  One of the installers I run requires answering some questions.  For example:

```
Is the default install folder ok (yes/no)?
What is the email address you would like to use?
```

The installer does not provide an option to script responses.  Is there a way to identify these prompts when running the installer from a bash script, and automatically providing a response?  For example:

```
Is the default install folder ok (yes/no)? yes
What is the email address you would like to use? my@address.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the tool called [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you can use [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a cast statement, like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Do you agree with this? [yes or no]: "
read yno
case $yno in

        [yY] | [yY][Ee][Ss] )
                echo "Agreed"
                ;;

        [nN] | [n|N][O|o] )
                echo "Not agreed, you can't proceed the installation";
                exit 1
                ;;
        *) echo "Invalid input"
            ;;
esac

$ ./yorno.sh
Do you agree with this? [yes or no]: YES
Agreed
```